# Is there any clean way to get a top-hat shape when using fieldsets with css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a fieldset to have a shape something like this:

```
      /-----------\
      |           |
      |           |
      |           |
  ____/           \____
 /                     \
 |                     |
 |                     |
 \_____________________/
```

Here's my best attempt so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/VWfVZ/

The problems I'm having is that I never can get it to line up correctly, and when I do, it seems to shift around depending on the content I have inside the fieldset.  Can anyone help me fix my css?  Or should I stop trying to go for this shape using a fieldset altogether?

Comment: Well I guess the most important question is - is it actually for a form or not?  (I double-check because there's no inputs in your jsfiddle.)

Comment: Yes, form data will be inside.

Comment: Simple question here, but why?  Could you not just use a container `div` with a css `background-image`?

Comment: @MTcoster - I didn't want to mess around with images if I didn't have to.  It's not a big deal.  I'm ok with how it looks now anyway, I just spent an hour or so messing with it this morning trying to get it to look how I wanted but never could, so I thought I'd throw it on SO and see if anyone had done something similar that worked for them.  Maybe I'll get some more time this weekend and create a css solution that works.

Comment: It is possible to get it to line up correctly, but you're always going to get anti-alaising issues on the corners, especially if the top border doesn't exist, as it will start to fade between black to nothing. The best way would be to include a top border on the bottom fieldset, and position it behind the div above. Then give the div a white background. That will only work if the fieldset bg is the same colour as the elements behind it however. You need to play around a bit with the widths to line up perfectly. Pixel perfect layouts are fragile however.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my one-element answer: http://jsfiddle.net/VWfVZ/29/

```
.hat {
position: relative;
background: none;
border: 1px solid #333;
width:300px;
height:50px;
margin-top:200px;
border-radius:15px;
}
.hat:after {
bottom: 100%;
content:" ";
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
width:220px;
height:100px;
border-top: 1px solid #333;
border-left: 1px solid #333;
border-right: 1px solid #333;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
left: 35px;
border-radius:25px 25px 0 0;
}
```

Just place the form elements inside. Or do you need the text to be in the same places as your fiddle?

Comment: You definitely nailed the shape, but yeah my goal was to get some form elements in the top part of the hat as well as the bottom.  +1 for effort though.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Actually this gets pretty dang close to what I was hoping for because I can then float the form elements inside the hat.